# Get any days that have availablility from Cronofy

Tags: cronofy

Using the [availability API](https://docs.cronofy.com/developers/api/scheduling/availability/) is it possible to get the DAYS only between two query periods that a user has availability in their schedule based on the provided duration? It is unreasonable to receive and process 512 time slots to, for example, see if the user has availability in the month of May. Plus that might not even be enough data.

For example if a user has the following available:

- May 1 9am
- May 2 between 9 and 3pm
- May 3 no time
- May 4 ...

Could we get a result that says, the user has at least 1 hour (ie provided duration query) for these days? In this case it might return an array of dates like May 1/2/4/... or an array of time slots like May 1 9am, May 2 9am, May 4 10 am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not right now. But it's a request we've had before and we plan to support it later this year.

Comment: Is there no hacky way to do it? ie request only one hour/duration of availability per day to in essence get a list of time slots that we could then verify the user has at least one time slot per day?

Comment: There's not really I'm afraid, hence we're going to have to do some work to support it.